# not getting array value in awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, string-comparison

I want to insert array values with all other contents of testfile.ps into result.ps file but array values not getting printed,please help.
My requirement is every time condition is met array next index value should get printed with other contents of testfile.ps  into result.ps

actually arr[0] and arr[1] are big strings in my project but for simplicity i am editing it

```
#!/bin/bash
a[0]=""lineto""\n""stroke""
a[1]=""476.00"" ""26.00""

awk '{ if($1 == "(Page" ){for (i=0; i<2; i++){print $arr[i]; print $0; }} 
else print }' testfile.ps > result.ps
```

testfile.ps

```
(Page 1 of 2 )
move
(Page 1 of 3 )
"gsave""\n""2.00"" ""setlinewidth""\n"
```

result.ps should be

```
(Page 1 of 2 )
lineto
stroke
move
(Page 1 of 3 )
476.00 26.00
gsave
2.00
setlinewidth
```

means once second time condition is met array index should be incremented to 1 and it should print a[1]

i applied this approch also,with only single array element but not getting any output

```
awk -v "a0=$a[0]" 'BEGIN {a[0]=""lineto""stroke""; if($1 == "move" ){for (i in a){ print a0;print $0; }} else print }' testfile.txt
```

edited:
hi , I have resolved the issue up to some extent but stuck at one place, how can i compare two strings like      "a=476.00 1.00 lineto\nstroke\ngrestore\n" and     "b=26.00 moveto\n368.00 1.00 lineto\n" in awk command,     i am trying

```
awk -v "a=476.00 1.00 lineto\nstroke\ngrestore\n" -v "b=26.00 moveto\n368.00 1.00 lineto\n"  -v "i=$a" '{
if ($1 == "(Page" && ($2%2==0 || $2==1) && $3 == "of"){  
    print i; 
    if [ i == a ];then
        i=b; print $0;  
    fi 
else if [ i == b ];then 
        i=c; print $0;  
    fi
else print $0; 
}'testfile.txt
```

Comment: awk is not shell, it's a completely different tool with it's own syntax, variables, etc. You can't use shell variables in awk any more than you can use shell variables in C or Java. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: and even if shell and awk used the same variables, they would have to be spelled the same, i.e. `a[0] !- $arr[0]` ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: What do you expect from `$arr[i]`? Are you trying to refer to the shell array `a` defined above? It is not even the same name, and you can't (easily) get shell variables in awk...

Comment: @EdMorton: thanks for commets,I have edited the question for more clarity

Comment: @dawg:thanks for commets,I have edited the question for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

You are using in your awk program a variable `arr` which is never initialized.

In your case, you want to pass a variable from the shell to awk. From the awk man page:

```
   -v var=val
   --assign var=val
          Assign the value val to the variable var, before execution of the program  begins.   Such
          variable values are available to the BEGIN rule of an AWK program.
```

Hence, you need something like

```
awk -v "a0=$a[0]" -v "a1=$a[1]" .....
```

and in a BEGIN block, you can set up your array `arr` from the variables a0 and a1 in any way you want.

Comment: :hi ,as of now i tried with only a0,but it is not giving me any output, please help

awk -v "a0=$a[0]" 'BEGIN {a[0]=""lineto""stroke""; if($1 == "move" ){for (i in a){ print a0;print $0; }} else print }' testfile.txt

Comment: hi user1934428 , can u please correct it , I am not getting desired output awk -v s="gsave\ninitmatrix\n 2.00 setlinewidth \n 368.00 26.00 moveto \n 368.00 1.00 lineto" ' BEGIN { n=split(s,a,"\n") } 1 /((Page && $2~/^[0-9][0-9]*/ && $2%2==0 && $3== "of")/ && i<n { print s } ' testfile.txt

Comment: Please post code properly formatted. You can do it by **editing** you original posting.

Comment: hi , my issue is resolved up to some extent but I am stuck at comparing two long alphanumeric strings in awk command, please have a look at above edited part of question

Comment: Comparing two strings is done with the `==` operator, but I notice several oddities: (1) You initialize the awk variable `i` by the shell variable `$a`, which, since this is a bash array, be equivalent to the first element of the array. (2) You use funny square brackets after the `if` in your awk program. Lookup the awk man page: You need round brackets. (3) You have no space in front of *testfile.txt*

Comment: my issue is resolved now with many more modifications and with your suggestions also , i am thankful to you..

Answer (score 0):

Gather the data to a single var using a separator:

```
$ awk -v s="lineto\nstroke;476.00 26.00" '  # ; as separator
BEGIN{ n=split(s,a,";") }                   # split s var to a array
1                                           # output record
/\(Page/ && i<n { print a[++i] }            # if (Page and still data in a
' file
(Page 1 of 2 )
lineto
stroke
move
(Page 1 of 3 )
476.00 26.00
"gsave""\n""2.00"" ""setlinewidth""\n"
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please, edit your question to reflect the real situation.

Comment: hi James , can u please correct it , I am not getting desired output
awk -v s="gsave\ninitmatrix\n 2.00 setlinewidth \n 368.00 26.00 moveto \n 368.00 1.00 lineto" '
BEGIN { n=split(s,a,"\n") }                
1                                          
/(\(Page && $2~/^[0-9][0-9]*/ && $2%2==0 && $3== "of")/ && i<n { print s }           
' testfile.txt

Comment: Well, no wonder, the condition part is fubar and your data does not match those conditions ever since `$2` is always 1. This is more like it: `awk -v s="gsave\ninitmatrix\n 2.00 setlinewidth \n 368.00 26.00 moveto \n 368.00 1.00 lineto" ' BEGIN { n=split(s,a,"\n") } 1; $1=="(Page" && $2~/^[0-9][0-9]*/ && $2%2==0 && $3== "of" && i<n { print s } ' file`

Comment: hi James , i have added real situation in main question ,please try to get it and help me in this... what should be the change in your answer

Comment: hi , my issue is resolved up to some extent but I am stuck at comparing two long alphanumeric strings in awk command, please have a look at above edited part of question